# "In der Beratung" or "Bei der Beratung"

Tags: preposition

I need to write a cover letter for a job application, but I'm not sure which preposition would be correct in my context - "in" or "bei". This is my sentence:

> Gerne bringe ich meine sehr gute Englischkenntnisse ein, die in/bei der Beratung ausländischer Kunden nützlich sein können.

Which is the correct alternative and why?

Comment: The usual preposition would be _bei_, but in consulting, where Beratung is the business model, _in_ is more appropriate [see #2](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=in+der+Beratung&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Zeitung&format=max&sort=date_desc&limit=50&p=1)

Comment: _Gerne bringe ich meine sehr gute Englischkenntnisse ein_ muss _Gerne bringe ich meine sehr gute**n** Englischkenntnisse ein_ lauten. Warum schreibst Du Deine Bewerbung nicht in Englisch, das wäre sehr überzeugend.

Comment: Ich würde in diesem Fall _bei_ wählen. Klingt einfach besser.

Comment: quite oversubtle question would one say who don't know the answer ... I'll try do give one. :)

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the comments, *bei* is the usual preposition here.

I would consider *in* appropriate in two cases:

1. It is about a conrete consultation. When one gets a phone call during a consultation, one could say: "Wir reden später. Ich bin gerade in einer Beratung." ("Let's talk later. I'm in a consultation") Another possiblity is a report: "In der Beratung kamen wir zum Ergebnis, dass..." ("During the consultation we came to the conclusion that...") But *bei* is also possible here.
2. There is a context in which *in* works well. This would be the case with sentences like "Ich habe Erfahrung in der Beratung von ...", since *Erfahrung haben in* is a common phrase.

Since these cases don't apply in the example sentence, *bei* is to be preferred IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

**in or bei**

> Which is the correct alternative and why?

They are both the same correct.

Checking some other sentences you will see that in and bei are used similar in cases where the  Englisch original is for and in (or may be at)

here are examples for 
in dringenden Angelegenheiten:

https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/bei+dringenden+angelegenheiten.html

https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/in+dringenden+angelegenheiten.html

however looking up right your question there are 4 examples  with **bei** and only one using **in**.

You can look up LINGUEE English-German and you won't find a difference in use or semantic  meaning, while there may be a statistic preference of the use of **bei**

Don't break your head any longer.